# Isolate a variable length number in a string using regex in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I am attempting to parse strings to find a variable length number within a string.

Here are some strings I'm testing against...

this_is_a_test_string25365with_a_number

this_is_another_test243with_a_number

testing_again3with_a_number

```
$Regex = "\b.*([\d]{1,}).*\b"
foreach($result in $testdata) {
    if( $result -match $Regex ) {
            $Matches[1]
    }
}
```

When I change the quantifier behind the \d it only gives me that number of digits

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the last sentence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That .* is going to be "greedy" and suck up everything up to the minimum number of digits needed to satisfy the match.

One way to fix that:

```
$Regex = "\b\D*([\d]{1,}).*\b"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to isolate just the number, you don't need the word boundaries with `\b` and the wildcards `.*`.  You want just your numbers to match.

You want to use `[\d]+` which says, any digit with 1 or more in a row.

Based on your examples, look [here for validation.](http://rubular.com/r/bKUFldxXR9) for validation

However: if you want to capture the entire string, you can leave the word bounds and the wildcards on both ends and it will capture the full string.  [Example here](http://rubular.com/r/VLN0gwKbV1)